# Proving continuity using Weierstrass M-test

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-continuity

I am asked to use the Weierstrass M-test to show that the following function is continuous on $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x+n} + \frac{1}{x-n}$$

My problem to solve this exercise is indeed to find the suitable bound $M_n$ , since the function

$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x+n} + \frac{1}{x-n}$ has two vertical asymptotes at $\pm n$

Comment: Well you can obviously give up on applying it directly to your functions $f_n(x)$ since $\sup_{x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z} |f_n(x)| = \infty$ by your remark, so you cannot find $M_n$. But it is possible you could re-arrange the partial sums so that you re-write this series as the convergent series of another sequence on functions on which you can apply the Weierstrass $M$-test.

Comment: As an aside, $f(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)-\dfrac1x~.~$ This can be shown by differentiating the natural logarithm of Euler's [infinite product expression for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: I do not figure out how to rearrange the series to get bounded functions.